# Storing data of currently signned user in Firebase Firestore in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I am new to Android. I create sign-in and sign-up functionality. But I want to store the data of the user,(before going to the signing screen) when the user is signing up in the FireBase FireStore (based on the current user id). I have the user id, but I don't know the way to do it. The code is attached below. I am glad, If someone could help.

```
package com.example.firebase
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Binder
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.Toast
import com.example.firebase.databinding.ActivitySignUpBinding
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore

class Sign_Up_Activity : AppCompatActivity() {


private lateinit var binding: ActivitySignUpBinding
private lateinit var firebaseAuth: FirebaseAuth
private lateinit var firebasefirestore: FirebaseFirestore

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    binding = ActivitySignUpBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)

    setContentView(binding.root)

    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
    firebasefirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()


      binding.signUpButton.setOnClickListener {


         val email = binding.emailEt.text.toString()
        val password = binding.passET.text.toString()
        val confirmPass = binding.confirmPassEt.text.toString()


        if (email.isNotEmpty() && password.isNotEmpty() && confirmPass.isNotEmpty()) {
            if (password.equals(confirmPass)) {

                firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                    .addOnCompleteListener {

                        if (it.isSuccessful) {

                            val userid:String= firebaseAuth.currentUser!!.uid

                            firebasefirestore.collection("user").document(userid).get()



                            Log.d("User id",userid)

                            val intent = Intent(this, Sign_In_Activity::class.java)
                            startActivity(intent)

                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(this, it.exception.toString(), 
  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                .show()
                        }
                    }


            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Password is not matching", 
  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Empty Fields are not Allowed", 
  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }

  }
 }
```

Comment: Since you're using Kotlin, I recommend you check this [approach](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-authenticate-to-firebase-using-google-one-tap-in-jetpack-compose-60b30e621d0d). Besides that, what exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: The code is working properly. But once user signed up, I want to save the information in firestore as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're using the following line of code:

```
firebasefirestore.collection("user").document(userid).get()
```

You aren't setting the user to Firestore, you're only reading it. If you want to add the data to the database, you have to use [set()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentReference#set(java.lang.Object)) like in the following lines of code:

```
val db = Firebase.firestore
val user = mapOf("email" to firebaseAuth.currentUser!!.email)
val userRef = db.collection("user")
userRef.document(userid).set(user)
                        .addOnSuccessListener { Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot successfully written!") }
                        .addOnFailureListener { e -> Log.w(TAG, "Error writing document", e) }
```

If you're interested in implementing Firebase authentication with Google, then please check the following article:

- [How to authenticate to Firebase using Google One Tap in Jetpack Compose?](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-authenticate-to-firebase-using-google-one-tap-in-jetpack-compose-60b30e621d0d)

If you want by chance to implement the anonymous authentication, then please check:

- [How to handle Firebase Authentication in clean architecture using Jetpack Compose?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-handle-firebase-authentication-in-clean-architecture-using-jetpack-compose-e9929c0e31f8)

Comment: I understand it. But I don't how to code after addonCompleteListener().

Comment: I made it simpler, as in the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data). So please check my updated answer. Is it ok now?